# how to stop a batch file outputting everything it does to a logfile?

Tags: batch-file

I've tried to reduce this post as much as possible without leaving out information TL;DR included at bottom.

I have inherited a script that, in short

- checks 2 folders on server A for images and text files
- copies the text files to a    destination folder on Server B
- copies the image files to a image    destination folder on Server B
- archives these files on Server A
- deletes any files older than 5 days on Server A

here is said script

```
@echo on
set log=c:\temp\acsloadcopy.log

set txtsrc=C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc
set imgsrc=C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc

set txtdest=C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtdest
set imgdest=C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgdest

set txtbak=%txtsrc%\Archive
set imgbak=%imgsrc%\Archive

rem set txtautonomy=\\idolget\tm\%TM10Environment%\

if ("%tm10acis%"=="") (
    call :stop 1 "No tmacis environment variable set - can't run" 
)

if ("%tm10acis%"=="none") (
    call :stop 0 "No Acs server for this environment (tmacis=none)"
)

set _hh=%time:~0,2%
if "%time:~0,1%"==" " set _hh=0%_hh:~1,1%
SET TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%-%_hh%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%

call :clean

call :dochecks
REM call :checkage %txtsrc%

REM COPY TO ACSE
xcopy  %txtsrc%\*.* %txtdest%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "error copying %txtsrc% %txtdest%"

xcopy  %imgsrc%\*.* %imgdest%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "error copying %imgsrc% %imgdest%"

REM to ARCHIVE
move /y %txtsrc%\*.* %txtbak%\%TIMESTAMP%
rem Xcopy %txtsrc%\*.* %txtbak%\%TIMESTAMP%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "error moving %txtsrc% %txtbak%\%TIMESTAMP%"

move /y %imgsrc%\*.* %imgbak%\%TIMESTAMP%
rem Xcopy %imgsrc%\*.* %imgbak%\%TIMESTAMP%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "error moving %imgsrc% %imgbak%\%TIMESTAMP%"


REM CLEAN UP OLD ARCHIVES

call :clean %txtbak%
call :clean %imgbak%

goto :eof

:dochecks
call :checkfolder %txtsrc% 
call :checkfolder %imgsrc%
call :checkfolder %txtdest%
call :checkfolder %imgdest%
call :checkfolder %txtbak%
call :checkfolder %imgbak%

if not exist %txtbak%\%TIMESTAMP% mkdir %txtbak%\%TIMESTAMP%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "Can't create archive folder %txtbak%\%TIMESTAMP% " 
if not exist %imgbak%\%TIMESTAMP% mkdir %imgbak%\%TIMESTAMP%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "Can't create archive folder %imgbak%\%TIMESTAMP% " 
if exist %txtdest%\*.txt call :stop 1 "Previouly copied text files have not been processed by acs"
if exist %imgdest%\*.jpg call :stop 1 "Previouly copied image files have not been processed by acs"
if not exist %txtsrc%\*.txt call :stop 0 "No source text files"
if not exist %imgsrc%\*.jpg call :stop 0 "No source image files"

:skipcheck
goto :eof

:checkfolder
set f=%1
pushd %f%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop "folder %f% does not exist"
popd 
goto :eof

:stop
set exitcode=%1
set exitmsg=%~2

echo %exitmsg%
exit %exitcode%
```

My problem is that the log is outputting EVERYTHING the batch file is doing here's an example of some of it:

```
C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "error copying 

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtdest" 

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>xcopy  C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc\*.* C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgdest 
C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc\dwqd.jpg
1 File(s) copied

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "error copying C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgdest" 

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>REM to ARCHIVE 

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>move /y C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc\*.* C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc\Archive\2017-03-08-10-34-41 
C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc\awd.txt
C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc\dwdw.txt
C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc\wwqwq.txt
        3 file(s) moved.

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>rem Xcopy C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc\*.* C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc\Archive\2017-03-08-10-34-41 

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "error moving C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\txtsrc\Archive\2017-03-08-10-34-41" 

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>move /y C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc\*.* C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc\Archive\2017-03-08-10-34-41 
C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc\dwqd.jpg
        1 file(s) moved.

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>rem Xcopy C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc\*.* C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc\Archive\2017-03-08-10-34-41 

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "error moving C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\imgsrc\Archive\2017-03-08-10-34-41" 

C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>REM to AUTONOMY 

    C:\Users\LCI\Desktop\testt>rem if ERRORLEVEL 1 call :stop 1 "error creating \2017-03-08-10-34-41"
```

This is especially noisy as it does some Julian date calculations (I've taken these out of the script I posed in order to reduce the already wall of text!) which end up being thousands of lines long.

As you can see it just outputs every line as it goes through, regardless of if it completes successfully or not, making interpretation a pain if something goes wrong.

I just want the log to display if it completed partially/successfully, and/or if it encountered an error (as can be seen above):

```
C:\Users\LCIAV\Desktop\txtsrc\awd.txt
C:\Users\LCIAV\Desktop\txtsrc\dwdw.txt
C:\Users\LCIAV\Desktop\txtsrc\wwqwq.txt
    3 file(s) moved )
```

I have tried adding an output pipe to only the lines that are of use to me (xcopy and IF's) within the script - this changed nothing,

I've tried calling the file via another batch file with a filter piped at the end, this sort of worked but was turning into a bit of a headache trying to account for everything I wanted.

I'm at a lose as it why it's outputting everything and how to resolve it

I would appreciate help understanding why it's outputting everything and how to resolve it.

regards

TL;DR batch file log is extremely noisy, outputting everything it does - would like to reduce it to output useful information only i.e. did it complete or did it error (and why!)

Comment: Well you define a variable at the top of your script for a log file name but I do not see a single instance of redirecting any output to that log file.

Comment: First line of your program, you set `echo on`.  Then you are surprised that echo is on?  If you don't want to see every command echo'd, set `echo off`.  This is not surprising.

Comment: @abelenky cheers for responding. I'm not surprised it is on. turning it"off" just outputs "echo is off" into the log

Comment: Also, i'm happy that the question was marked down - but an explanation as to why would be nice. I thought I made it clear I was given the script its not my creation. I probably should have also added my skill level with batch files, which is why I was asking for help to understand the problem

Comment: The command `echo` will respond with `echo is off`.  The command `@echo off` will set echo to be Off, and disable all further echoing.  I think @Magoo's answer is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
@echo on
```

to

```
@echo off
```

which will turn off the command-echoing.

as you say, TL;DR. You can then choose to output to screen by `echo`ing any string you want to, or disposing if any unwanted output by appending `>nul` to the lines-not-wanted and possibly `2>nul` to suppress error-messages.

Comment: thanks for responding, i'll have a play about with that

Comment: thank you. I was able to use this to out put only everything I needed